# PHP confirmation not working

Tags: php

i am creating a booking system for university, and i am struggling to get my code working,

The SQL works, but i cannot find why the code is breaking and wanted some help

```
<?php
    $title = 'Confirm The Booking';
    require_once 'header.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $confirmed = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, trim($_POST['Confirmed']));
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, trim($_POST['name']));
        $tid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, trim($_POST['tid']));

        if(!empty($tid)){

            $query = "UPDATE room1booking
                    SET Confirmed = '1'
                    WHERE id = 'tid'";
            mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

            echo '<p>You have successfully booked the room for ' . $name . '.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>There is a problem with the system.</p>';

}
?>
```

There is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated, i think it is something to do with tid, but not entirely sure

*edit*

```
    <?php
    $title = 'room Booking';
    require_once 'header.php';
?>
<ul>
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `room1booking` ORDER BY date & start & id";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo '<li>
                        ' . $row['name'] . '
                        ' . $row['date'] . '
                        ' . $row['start'] . '
                        <button type="submit"><a href="confirmBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '">Confirm</a></button>
                        <button><a href="denyBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '">Deny</a></button>
                     </li>';
            }

        } else {
            echo '<li>There are no results</li>';
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }


    mysqli_close($db_server);
?>
</ul>
```

I have added in more code in terms of what i need help fixing. This is the page that displays all bookings

Where do i need to set up submit?

Comment: `WHERE id = '$tid'";` missing `$`

Comment: ^ That - Without the `$` you are searching for a ID that is `tid` and not the variable `$tid`'s content.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, i have tried this just, and it still wont change the 0 to a 1 in the database, and still says there is an error with the system

Comment: Post your error code too!!

Comment: i just have a <p> echo onto the screen is there is a problem..

Comment: If the error is `There is a problem with the system.` from your own code, it's because the `$_POST['submit']` isn't set and it's a issue with your form.

Comment: how do i fix this?

Comment: You check for errors and/ or you post the html form

Comment: @Fred -ii- I have added the other page relating to the error. Any suggestions

Comment: why '&' in "SELECT * FROM `room1booking` ORDER BY date & start & id" ?   write ',' instead of '&'

Comment: thanks user, still trying to figure out why it wont work

Comment: looking at the first section of code i posted, i managed to fix it saying there is a problem with the system, now it says undefined index :/